# many to many relationship querybuilder doctrine and symfony2 extended query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I am applying following query using querybuilder but somehow many2many relationship is not working as expected.

```
$shopData = $sm->createQueryBuilder()                    
                ->select('v')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Voucher','v')
                ->innerJoin('v.shop', 's')
                ->leftJoin('AdminBundle:VoucherProgram', 'vp', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON, 'vp.id = v.program_id')
                ->leftJoin('AdminBundle:shopHistory', 'sh', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::ON, 'sh.shop = s.id')
                ->where('s.shopStatus = :shopStatus')
                ->setParameter('shopStatus', Shop::SHOP_ACTIVATED)
                ->andWhere('s.highlightedHome = :highlightedHome')
                ->setParameter('highlightedHome', Shop::SHOP_HIGHLIGHTED_HOME)
                ->andWhere('s.offers = \'voucher\'')
                ->setFirstResult(0)
                ->setMaxResults(6)
                ->addOrderBy('v.discount_amount', 'DESC')
                ->groupBy('sh.shop')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getSql();
```

Generated query looks like below:

```
SELECT v FROM AdminBundle:Voucher v INNER JOIN v.shop s LEFT JOIN AdminBundle:VoucherPrograms vp ON vp.id = v.program_id LEFT JOIN AdminBundle:shopHistory sh ON sh.shop = s.id WHERE s.shopStatus = :shopStatus AND s.highlightedHome = :highlightedHome AND s.offers = 'voucher' GROUP BY sh.shop ORDER BY v.discount_amount DESC
```

In case if I remove everything and keep only inner join for Many2Many relation, it is working as expected.

```
$sm->createQueryBuilder()                    
                ->select('v')
                ->from('AdminBundle:Voucher','v')
                ->innerJoin('v.shop', 's');
```

Here is the generated query:

```
SELECT l0.* FROM voucher l0_ INNER JOIN shop_voucher l2_ ON l0_.id = l2_.voucher_id INNER JOIN shop l1_ ON l1_.id = l2_.shop_id;
```

So I am wondering why system is not picking up correct relation when I add more joins.

Here is my main entities having Many2Many relationship:

Shop.php

```
namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Shop.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Entity\ShopRepository")
 */
class Shop
{
    const SHOP_DEACTIVATED = 0;
    const SHOP_ACTIVATED = 1;
    const SHOP_HIGHLIGHTED_HOME = 1;
    ................................
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Voucher", inversedBy="shop")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="shop_voucher")
     */
    private $voucher;
    ................................
```

Voucher.php

```
namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
#use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Voucher.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="voucher")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Entity\VoucherRepository")
 */
class Voucher
{
    ................................
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Shop", mappedBy="voucher", cascade={"persist"})    
     */
    private $shop;
    ................................
```

I have already checked on stack having same questions but I want to know how we can extend query. I have the solution for my question as below but not getting exactly what is happening in above scenario.

```
$shopDataQuery = $connection->prepare('SELECT v.* FROM voucher AS v INNER JOIN shop_voucher AS sv ON sv.voucher_id = v.id INNER JOIN shop AS s ON s.id = sv.shop_id LEFT JOIN voucher_programs AS vp ON vp.id = v.program_id LEFT JOIN shop_history AS sh ON sh.shop = s.id WHERE s.shopStatus = :shopStatus AND s.highlightedHome = :highlightedHome AND s.offers = 'voucher' GROUP BY sh.shop ORDER BY v.discount_amount DESC LIMIT 6');
```

---

Update:

Here is the shopHistory.php

```
namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * shopHistory.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_history")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Entity\shopHistoryRepository")
 */
class shopHistory
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop", inversedBy="shopHistory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $shop;
```

Here is VoucherProgram.php

```
namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * VoucherProgram.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="voucher_program")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdminBundle\Entity\VoucherProgramRepository")
 */
class VoucherProgram
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Voucher", mappedBy="program")
     */
    private $voucher;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shop", mappedBy="vprogram")
     */
    private $shop;
```

Comment: Checks `->groupBy('sh.shop')` this statement, this require the column id from shop entity in `select` clausule.

Comment: I have commented groupby but result is same or not getting exactly what do you mean.

Comment: How do you get queries?
The first one seems to be the DQL query (so no join columns are specified if you didn't force them) and the second one is the SQL query

Comment: No issue in second SQL query. First DQL contains innerJoin which is getting correct relationship automatically based on Many2Many relation if I don't add any other joins but if I do, relationship is not picking up.

Comment: You are using group by but i can see there is no aggregate function is used so what's the purpose of using it, you query may provide your desired output but logically its wrong

Comment: The purpose of adding group is to exclude duplicate shop records.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because you have named your relation as same as your field :

```
SELECT v 
FROM AdminBundle:Voucher v 
INNER JOIN v.shop s 
LEFT JOIN AdminBundle:VoucherPrograms vp ON vp.id = v.program_id 
LEFT JOIN AdminBundle:shopHistory sh ON sh.shop = s.id 
WHERE s.shopStatus = :shopStatus 
AND s.highlightedHome = :highlightedHome 
AND s.offers = 'voucher' 
GROUP BY sh.shop 
ORDER BY v.discount_amount DESC
```

Try to rename in your **shopHistory** Entity the field **shop** as **shop_id**.

But I don't have the full entity model to make tests !

If this isn't it, try to paste the code of your 5 entities, please...

**Edit :**

I make tests on my local machine with a symfony 2.8 edition.

I have generated entities form given model.

I have just added this in *Voucher* Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="voucherProgram", inversedBy="voucher")
 */
private $program;
```

I've this queries :

My first Query

```
SELECT v 
FROM AppBundle:Voucher v 
INNER JOIN v.shop s 
LEFT JOIN AppBundle:voucherProgram vp WITH vp.id = v.program 
LEFT JOIN AppBundle:shopHistory sh 
WITH sh.shop = s.id 
GROUP BY sh.shop
```

My second SQL Query

```
SELECT v0_.id AS id0, v0_.program_id AS program_id1 
FROM voucher v0_ 
INNER JOIN shop_voucher s2_ ON v0_.id = s2_.voucher_id 
INNER JOIN shop s1_ ON s1_.id = s2_.shop_id 
LEFT JOIN voucher_program v3_ ON (v3_.id = v0_.program_id) 
LEFT JOIN shop_history s4_ ON (s4_.shop = s1_.id) 
GROUP BY s4_.shop 
LIMIT 6 
OFFSET 0
```

I think that what is generated is correct !

Edit 2 :

I try with a symfony standard edition with :

```
$shopData = $this->getDoctrine()
  ->getManager()
  ->createQueryBuilder()                    
  ->select('v')
  ->from('AppBundle:Voucher','v')
  ->innerJoin('v.shop', 's')
  ->leftJoin('AppBundle:voucherProgram', 'vp', 'WITH', 'vp.id = v.program')
  ->leftJoin('AppBundle:shopHistory', 'sh', 'WITH', 'sh.shop = s.id')
  //->where('s.shopStatus = :shopStatus')
  //->setParameter('shopStatus', Shop::SHOP_ACTIVATED)
  //->andWhere('s.highlightedHome = :highlightedHome')
  //->setParameter('highlightedHome', Shop::SHOP_HIGHLIGHTED_HOME)
  //->andWhere('s.offers = \'voucher\'')
  ->setFirstResult(0)
  ->setMaxResults(6)
  //->addOrderBy('v.discount_amount', 'DESC')
  ->groupBy('sh.shop')
  ->getQuery()
  ->getDql();
```

My composer.json is :

```
"php": ">=5.3.9",
"symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
```

And my Entities :

**Shop**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Shop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShopRepository")
 */
class Shop
{
    const SHOP_DEACTIVATED = 0;
    const SHOP_ACTIVATED = 1;
    const SHOP_HIGHLIGHTED_HOME = 1;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Voucher", inversedBy="shop")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="shop_voucher")
     */
    private $voucher;
}
```

**shopHistory**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * shopHistory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="shop_history")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\shopHistoryRepository")
 */
class shopHistory
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop", inversedBy="shopHistory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $shop;
}
```

**Voucher**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Voucher
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="voucher")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VoucherRepository")
 */
class Voucher
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Shop", mappedBy="voucher", cascade={"persist"})    
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="voucherProgram", inversedBy="voucher")
     */
    private $program;
}
```

**voucherProgram**

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * voucherProgram
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="voucher_program")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\voucherProgramRepository")
 */
class voucherProgram
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Voucher", mappedBy="program")
     */
    private $voucher;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shop", mappedBy="vprogram")
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: The SQL query is working fine but i want to know why querybuilder is not giving correct relation. I will give a try to change the field the way you are suggesting but it is having same column name - "shop_id" in table.

Comment: I think querybuilder is not giving the correct relation maybe because there are to "shop" in your query. Can you please paste a give me by another way a example code (not entire) of your 5 entities ? I will try to help you has I can I my local machine...

Comment: Ok, I will make some tests in my local machine as soon as possible

Comment: Let me try out.

Comment: Have you get the time to test ? I can help you if I can !

Comment: No problem, try to have a look If my test is good, when you can !!

Comment: Have you got the time to test ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see the first given query is `DQL` query and the second is `SQL` query. DQL queries could be much more shorter and still works as expected as it does not operates tables but entites. So you need less joins to join m2m relation (which are expanded into double join when generating final `SQL`)

I cannot find anything wrong with generated DQL in case it is generated with given query builder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I want. Neither DQL nor SQL is wrong. But DQL without any additional joins, gives correct relationship whereas with more join, relation is changed, it should be same as SQL.

Comment: `DQL` is not ought to be same as `SQL`. It is the higher abstraction level. Can you update post with both `actual` and `expected` queries, as I really cannot understand what's wrong to inspect

Comment: SQL is the expected and actual query and what I want to do is to convert it to DQL.